# There was an error loading payments.Please refresh or try again later. PWA Venia Theme Magento2.4 issue coming on

Tags: magento2, progressive-web-apps, venia

I have installed PWA Venia Theme with magento2.4.1 EE but on checkout, no payment methods are loading. Error Getting: There was an error loading payments. Please refresh or try again later. Attached the image below Is anyone faced the same issue? or anyone has any information regarding this issue?
[image: Payment Gateway Error]

Answer (score 1):

enable Braintree in the admin
stores > configuration > sales > payment methods > Braintree
you can get sandbox keys from
https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/